# How to use debuild hooks (--signing-hook-foo etc)

Tags: debian, dpkg, hook

The man page isn't [clear on that](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/devscripts/debuild.1.en.html#HOOKS).

How would I use a signing hook? Especially using the parameter without the config file.
What is the meaning of `foo` in the documentation? For example in `--signing-hook-foo`? Do I replace `foo` with my bash script? The would seem very odd and against all conventions that I know.

For example, would this be the way you are supposed to use it?

```
echo "#!/usr/bin/env bash" > /signing-hook-script.sh
echo "(pwd; ls -la; tree /) > /output.txt" >> /signing-hook-script.sh
chmod +x /signing-hook-script.sh

debuild -i -S --signing-hook-/signing-hook-script.sh
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well spotted, the manpage is incorrect. `debuild --help` shows the appropriate syntax:

```
    --dpkg-buildpackage-hook=HOOK
    --clean-hook=HOOK
    --dpkg-source-hook=HOOK
    --build-hook=HOOK
    --binary-hook=HOOK
    --dpkg-genchanges-hook=HOOK
    --final-clean-hook=HOOK
    --lintian-hook=HOOK
    --signing-hook=HOOK
    --post-dpkg-buildpackage-hook=HOOK
                        These hooks run at the various stages of the
                        dpkg-buildpackage run.  For details, see the
                        debuild manpage.  They default to nothing, and
                        can be reset to nothing with --foo-hook=''
```

So your example would be

```
debuild --signing-hook=/signing-hook-script.sh -i -S
```

(`debuild` options must be specified before `dpkg-buildpackage` options).

Comment: How would one go about correcting the issue with the manpage?

Comment: Clone the repository (`debcheckout devscripts`), edit `scripts/debuild.1`, and submit the resulting patch using `reportbug`. (If any of that isn’t clear, ask and I’ll expand my answer.)

Comment: Hm, I get `dpkg-buildpackage: error: unknown option or argument --signing-hook=/signing-hook-script.sh` when running `debuild -i -S --signing-hook=/signing-hook-script.sh`.

Comment: Ah yes, see my update.